# How to attach rigged cloth with a rigged character.?

Tags: objects, rigging, armature, parent

Guys i am in a big problem and don't know how to do that.i want to attach rigged skirt/cloth with my rigged character i don't wan't to lost cloth bones.[image]

Comment: Character Creation Vol.2 covers rigging with cloth sims. http://www.cgmasters.net/training-dvds/character-creation-rigging/  So it's definitely possible, and I'm sure the training course is great. Sorry, I don't know of any free tutorials just off the top of my head though.

Comment: Re-reading your post, it looks like you've already succeeded in rigging the cloth, and just need that clothing armature to be joined with the body armature, in which case you can position it on the character as you need and then join the clothing armature(s) to the body armature. Then check your bone hierarchy to make sure it is a child of the body's root bone, or whatever bone you need it to be a child of. Then you'll need to make the body a collision object for the cloth. This is theory, I haven't tried something exactly like what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Child of constraint on the cloth armature to make it a Child of the body armature and a related bone. Then you can animate the strength of the constraint if you want to take it off. (Or use the addon for dynamic parents.)

Comment: can you please help me with some screenshots.

Comment: You can find more information in the [Blender Reference Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/relationship/child_of.html) for that process.